# How should I iterate through the results of multiple getElementsByClassName() calls in the same loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, concatenation, getelementsbyclassname

I'd like to do this:

```
a1 = document.getElementsByClassName('classA');
a2 = document.getElementsByClassName('classB');
a3 = a1.concat(a2);

for (var i=0; i<a3.length; ++i) {

}
```

i.e. get all the elements of classA, all the elements of classB and then combine them in a way that allows me to iterate through all of them. It doesn't work because getElementsByClassName doesn't return a standard array.

This works but there has to be a more sensible way:

```
var els = [];
var e1 = document.getElementsByClassName('classA');
var e2 = document.getElementsByClassName('classB');
[].forEach.call(e1, function(el) { els.push(el); });
[].forEach.call(e2, function(el) { els.push(el); });
```

Comment: Why? (That will  help to answer the question). Also - not sure if this concept is possible.  But, you could assign classC (aka "class Both") to the elements you want to iterate over.  So, element `could be class="classA classBoth"`

Comment: That's great. What's the problem?

Comment: Also, consider using jQuery, in which case you just need to do:

`$('.classA, .classB').each(function() {
    // this do something here
})`

Comment: Consider `querySelectorAll('.classA, .classB')` since I think qSA is more widely supported than getElementsByClassName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getElementsByClassName` method returns an `HTMLCollection` rather than an array. It's an array-like object, but you can't use all array methods on it.

Turn the collections into arrays using the `slice` method, then you can concatenate them:

```
var a3 = Array.prototype.slice.call(a1).concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(a2));
```

Note: This requires IE9 or later.

Comment: This is apt but I'm still curious if there is a better way to iterate multiple iteratables one after another as if they were one object, perhaps without constructing an array?

Comment: @AsksAnyway: Not to my knowledge. You could make an object that could access different collections depending on the index, but that would only move the complexity from the loop to the object, and it wouldn't be very efficient.

Comment: Don't treat host objects like native objects, there is no specification that says they must behave. The above will fail in IE 8 at least.

Answer (score 5):

In modern browsers you can use:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.classA, .classB');
```

This finds all elements with 'classA' or 'classB'.
You can find more info and a browser compatibility table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).

Comment: This works and I'm grateful but it is an alternative technique as opposed to a method to iterate multiple iterable objects as if they were one.

Comment: @AsksAnyway—given the OP, it's a better answer than the one you've accepted.

Comment: It answers the question "how do I select more than one class at once?" not how the iteration can be done.

Comment: It returns a single collection that can then be processed with a standard for, while or do loop. The selected answer creates two collections and 3 separate arrays. However, [performance is pretty similar](http://jsperf.com/array-vs-qsa) except for Firefox. Apart from not being supported by IE8, the array method is hard coded whereas qSA provides a general solution for any number of classes. And it's less to type. ;-)